# In order to downgrade to Mavericks from Yosemite do I need to reformat my hard drive and use the internet recovery to reinstall Mavericks?

Tags: hard-drive, macos

From the research I just did, it seems that I had to upgrade to Yosemity using a different drive!? Where as I added Yosemity into the main drive. Am I right in thinking that I now can  only downgrade by reformatting the hard drive (loosing my data and so forth)?

Apparently I'd be able to reinstall Mavericks via the internet holding command-option-r. Does this mean I don't need to have a copy of the Mavericks installer? And since I am re-formating the main drive, would this method still work.

Basically, apart from losing my data, and the hours it will take, is there a chance that I format the main drive and something going wrong and ending up without an operating system?

Comment: Please add your Mac model (e.g. MacBookPro9,1 or iMac11,1). Depending on your model several paths exist.

Comment: @klanomath MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today there is no known way to downgrade from Yosemite to Mavericks without erasing the drive.

Booting to the `internet recovery mode` <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> means that you boot to a netboot image containing a basic system downloaded from Apple/Akamai. You don't need the Mavericks installer. If you reinstall a system the system originally shipped  with your Mac will be loaded.

1. Boot process (takes 2 minutes connected to a 50 MBps-line):

   [image: netboot]
2. Boot process finished:

   [image: menu]

   Translation:
   Festplattendienstprogramm: Disk Utility
   OS X erneut installieren: Reinstall OS X
3. Starting `Disk Utility` looks like this:

   [image: diskutility]

   Now you just have to repartition your Macintosh HD: 1 Partition & GUID partition table (available via `Options`)
   If you stuck here unable to partition your drive because it's forbidden or greyed out, your Macintosh HD was probably converted to a CoreStorage Volume Group. Please check and execute the steps 10-12 of my answer to this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152645/attempting-to-revert-to-mac-os-x-mavericks-now-cant-get-out-of-os-x-utilities/152745#152745). Afterwards you have to start `Disk Utility` again and partition the drive to your needs.
   BTW: SystemUSB is an attached thumb drive with a bootable system and disk2 (OS X Base System) is the netboot image you downloaded and booted to earlier in step 1.
4. Quit `Disk Utility` to get to the menu again (picture 2)
5. Start `Reinstall OS X`. Now probably `Lion` is downloaded to your newly created hard disk partition and installed there afterwards.
   If you get a message like 'Could not find installation information for this machine' just restart your Mac to the `internet recovery mode`. (The netboot image seems to be very picky with the WLAN connection and it took me two attempts to get around this step)

If you choose the `recovery mode` <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> the latest system will be installed. You need a working `Recovery HD`-volume though. Such volume won't exist on a brand new hdd.

In both cases a stable and fast internet connection will be convenient.

Using the `internet recovery mode` you won't end up with an 'unbootable' system (depending on the reliability of your internet connection) because your (maybe falsely partioned) hdd is never involved in the (net)boot process.

In your case (MacBook Pro early 2011) i would download 'Mavericks' with your App Store account, create a ['Mavericks Installer' thumb drive](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372), boot to it and continue with step 2 outlined above. It's just faster and more reliable than first downloading and installing Lion and then Mavericks.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I understood it right. If I go with `internet recovery mode` would I just reformat the existing volume? Is there a change that after reformating the volume, the installer would not work and I end up with an empty drive?

Comment: after booting you have to format the drive with Disk Utility first and afterwards you choose  'Reinstall System' to download and install the original system. In your case this should be 'Lion' though it might be shipped with 'Snow Leopard'. I'll add a screenshot tomorrow. right now Im using an iPhone AWFK.

Comment: FYI, If the Mac originally shipped with Snow Leopard, internet recovery might not be available unless you have installed a firmware update from Apple.  http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4904

Comment: i will post an addendum when i get home. you didn't go with my proposal (thumb drive)?

Comment: I did it. I tried installing OS X (from the second option of step 2) that kept saying that it wasn't available at the time. So I used a thumb drive. Now I have done it! Thanks for your help

Comment: @aurel No system (SL or L) was available? Did you check Kent's [firmware update](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4904) proposal (3 posts above) or [latest firmware](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1237)?

Comment: @aurel i did the same steps also with a MBP (13") early 2011 about 4 weeks ago and i got Lion

Comment: My bad, I did not understand it before. So I could have downloaded "Macbook Pro EFI Firmware Update 2.3" and not needed the memory stick? cool

Comment: @aurel I don't know. But in my opinion the internet recovery mode (& system download) is a last resort only. I always prefer the thumb stick method, because - depending on your mac model & internet connection - it's more reliable and takes less time.

Comment: Aha, good job I did that then. Thanks a lot @klanomath