# restoring to mavericks from yosemite, partition disappeared after fail

Tags: hard-drive, macos, time-machine, restore

I have an mbpro 15" with 2 hard disks: 
Main: SSD with OS
Extra: Time machine backups and data

For different reasons I wanted to downgrade to Mavericks. I rebooted with cmd+r and went to time machine backups. Selected from the Extra HD and selected the Main to restore to. Insert Filevault PW, etc, next, etc. I clicked 'restore' and then it gave me an error:  "cannot restore" Without any specifics.

Rebooted and tried again but this time I didn't see my Main. I selected the time machine backup, because the Extra hard disk is there. But I couldn't choose Main as a restore point!

I checked with disk utility:

Both HD's are there. But it seems the partition dissapeared on my Main. I can't repartitions or format, the options aren't there.

Verify and repair disk didn't mention anything.

Who can help me restore to Mavericks? If not possible, restoring to yosemite is fine too, as long as I can use my Mac!

This is the output:

```
**-bash-3.2# diskutil cs list**
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 5B8350BF-20EF-4199-82E6-129EFF19E9EB
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         255200755712 B (255.2 GB)
    Free Space:   254855766016 B (254.9 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 907FCDE2-0C62-4951-A39E-36F19244FDB7
        ----------------------------------------------------
        Index:    0
        Disk:     disk0s2
        Status:   Online
        Size:     255200755712 B (255.2 GB)


**-bash-3.2# diskutil list**   
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         255.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *1.3 GB     disk1
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        1.3 GB     disk1s2
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Hitachi                 449.8 GB   disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS time machine            299.9 GB   disk2s3
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *5.2 MB     disk3
/dev/disk4
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk4
/dev/disk5
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk5
/dev/disk6
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk6
/dev/disk7
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk7
/dev/disk8
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk8
/dev/disk9
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *6.3 MB     disk9
/dev/disk10
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *2.1 MB     disk10
/dev/disk11
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk11
/dev/disk12
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk12
/dev/disk13
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk13
/dev/disk14
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk14
/dev/disk15
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *6.3 MB     disk15
-bash-3.2#
```

Comment: hi @klanomath I added the output, thanks for replying!

Comment: Essentially a Logical Volume Family & a Logical Volume are missing. You may either recreate those or delete the Logical Volume Group wIth some corestorage commands. BTW how did you manage to get the output of the two mentioned cmds posted here so fast in recovery mode?

Comment: You should try [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/), has saved my disks tons of times (you need an external OS to boot from though .)

Comment: @klanomath i copy and pasted the terminal output to a usb drive. Unfortunately I don't understand what else you're saying :) But now I'm following this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152645/attempting-to-revert-to-mac-os-x-mavericks-now-cant-get-out-of-os-x-utilities?rq=1

Comment: @flowen I will write an extended answer soon. At the moment i'm afk and using an iPhone to comment.

Comment: @listik Only DiskWarrior 5 (published a few days ago) can handle CoreStorage volumes.

Comment: @klanomath I'm using the answer I'm posting and it's already restoring right now. Just waiting for it to finish and double check if everything is okay :) Don't want to waste your time until then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your `CoreStorage Volume Group` got corrupted.

Usually a simple `CoreStorage Volume Group` looks like this:

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 9D2BA4BA-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         599640592384 B (599.6 GB)
    Free Space:   6111232 B (6.1 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 29A9A02B-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     599640592384 B (599.6 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 2FA7892F-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 7BF42B7B-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          599282155520 B (599.3 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Your LVG is missing a `Logical Volume Family` and a `Logical Volume`.

1. Restart into (Internet) Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup or boot from a thumb drive containing a bootable system/recovery system/bootable OS X installer.
2. Start  `Terminal` and enter following command at the Terminal prompt:
   `diskutil cs list`
3. Copy the Logical Volume Group (LVG) alphanumeric UUID of your CoreStorage volume. The LVG should be the first UUID listed and it’s the one you want to delete.
4. Next, run the following command:
   `diskutil cs delete UUID`
   In your case: `diskutil cs delete 5B8350BF-20EF-4199-82E6-129EFF19E9EB`
   This will delete your corrupted CoreStorage volume and reformat it as an unencrypted HFS+ volume.
   Quit Terminal
5. In the now opening window choose `Disk Utility` and format/partition the internal drive. 
   [image: Diskutil]
   Choose `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` and GUID partition table (available with the `option` button). Quit `Disk Utility`.
6. Plug in your `Time Machine` backup drive.
7. Start `Restore from Time Machine Backup` and recover your old system
   [image: TimeMachine]

Comment: I basically did that using the answer from http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152645/attempting-to-revert-to-mac-os-x-mavericks-now-cant-get-out-of-os-x-utilities?rq=1 but thanks for taking the time and it is EXACTLY what I did and what fixed the problem :)

Comment: @flowen i just took my answer there and adapted it to your question (and the different conditions)